# DateTime.ParseExact issue when no year present

Tags: .net, datetime

My code calls for parsing a yearless string from a dropdown menu into one with a year, in this case:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(DropDownList.Text, "dddd, MMMM dd", New CultureInfo("en-GB")).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
```

As we reach to turn over the year, I've hit the obvious problem, and receiving the format exception `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime because the day of week was incorrect.` for dates in the next year. Is there any easy way to handle this without having to handle these cases and set the year myself?

Comment: It is another object lesson for "separate the data and the view".  You should not have to parse the data back from the control.  And instead use DropDownList.SelectedIndex to retrieve the DateTime back from a List.  You can kludge it by catching the exception and appending (DateTime.Now.Year + 1).ToString() to the string.

Comment: Use: DisplayMember and ValueMember, so Display will be your UI format date, ValueMember will be your actual date with year.

Comment: @HansPassant yeah - I actually am using that kludge for now. The question is more if there is a way of changing the parseexact behaves.